# Prove that closure of $f(U)$ is compact in $Y$.

Tags: general-topology, continuity, compactness

Let $f: X \to Y$ be continuous, where $X$ is compact and $Y$ is Hausdorff. Let $K$ be a closed subset of $X$ and $U$ a proper subset of K. Prove that closure of $f(U)$ is compact in $Y$.
I have got this partial proof: http://topospaces.subwiki.org/wiki/Compact_to_Hausdorff_implies_closed
How to take it from here?
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the partial result $f(X)$ is closed in $Y$. Since $f(U)\subseteq f(X)$ we know that $\overline {f(U)}\subseteq f(X)$, so $\overline {f(U)}$ is a closed subset of the compact space $f(X)$ and hence compact.

Comment: @user: Another way is to note that $f(\overline U)=\overline{f(U)}$ since $f$ is closed. As $\overline U$ is a closed subset of $X$, and thus compact, so is its image $\overline{f(U)}$.